# Is my Y-chromosome the same at 78 as it was at 18?

Tags: dna-sequencing

How accurate is a Y-dna test at age 78?

Comment: For those who VTC -- I'm just wondering, how is this question seeking medical advice? The OP simply asks if the Y chromosome is vulnerable to aging, and, how accurate Y-DNA testing is.. Nothing about this question has to do with medicine, but instead, lies within general biology/genetics.

Comment: On the other hand, if you want to VTC due to lack of effort on the OPs part, to answer their own question, then I may agree with you..

Comment: Your Y-chromosome most likely isn't the exact same as it was 60 years ago, however, this isn't such a big deal since the Y-chromosome is some 60 million base pairs long. Generally speaking, the accuracy of a Y-DNA test is influenced by the type, and number, of markers used. That being said, age shouldn't diminish test result accuracy.

Answer (score 3):

By and large, yes.  Some telomeres might be shorter, but the rest of the sequence will not change.  Certainly, any regions used for ancestry testing will be stable.